# AWS AmazonKeyManagementServiceClient.decrypt() timed out on EC2 instance

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, amazon-kms

I am trying to use AWS KMS to decrypt data. I am able to use below code successfully locally but the request fails while deployed on EC2 instance. My EC2 is restricted subnet. Do i need to open some specific connection to EC2 to access AWS KMS?

the timeout happens at line

```
MemoryStream plainText = kmsClient.Decrypt(decryptRequest).Plaintext;


public static string DecryptCC(string data)
    {
        try
        {
            string decryptedString = string.Empty;
            byte[] stringForDecryption = Convert.FromBase64String(data);

            Console.WriteLine("heelo , I am in DC");

            //Move to config
            AmazonKeyManagementServiceConfig config = new AmazonKeyManagementServiceConfig();
            config.RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast2;
            var awsCredentials = new Amazon.Runtime.BasicAWSCredentials("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy");

            AmazonKeyManagementServiceClient kmsClient = new AmazonKeyManagementServiceClient(awsCredentials, config);
            Console.WriteLine("heelo , I am in DC after client");
            MemoryStream ciphertext = new MemoryStream();
            ciphertext.Write(stringForDecryption, 0, stringForDecryption.Length);

            DecryptRequest decryptRequest = new DecryptRequest()
            {
                CiphertextBlob = ciphertext,

            };
            MemoryStream plainText = kmsClient.Decrypt(decryptRequest).Plaintext;

            //var reader = new StreamReader(plainText);
            decryptedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainText.ToArray());


            if (decryptedString == null)
            {
                decryptedString = string.Empty;
            }

            return decryptedString;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't access *any* AWS services from inside EC2 unless *either* your instance has outbound Internet access *or* the service in question supports VPC endpoints, and you have an endpoint configured correctly.

See [Connecting to AWS KMS Through a VPC Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/kms-vpc-endpoint.html) in the KMS Developer Guide.

Comment: My instance has outbound internet accees.

Comment: What then is the meaning of *"My EC2 is restricted subnet"*?  A timeout error suggests your instance does not have Internet access.